# Categorical product in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are many examples of the coproduct in tikz with straight edges, however I can not find any (that work) or without a special package (other than tikz) for the product. I would just like to be able to be able to reproduce this picture of a [product](https://unapologetic.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/product_diagram.jpg) in tikz, or possibly another method that is easy to understand so as to update and add arrows if need be.

I have tried to turn the following in to the diagram that I would like, however all the arrows and everything get pushed together (the arrows are extremely small). My thought was to extend $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$ to the left, then of course change the symbols. Note that I got the following from [here](https://pdp7.org/blog/2011/02/how-to-draw-commutative-diagrams-in-latex-with-tikz/):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (C) {$C$};
  \node (P) [below of=C] {$\prod_{i \in I} A_i$};
  \node (Ai) [right of=P] {$A_i$};
  \draw[->] (C) to node {$f_i$} (Ai);
  \draw[->, dashed] (C) to node [swap] {$\langle f_i \rangle_{i \in I}$} (P);
  \draw[->] (P) to node [swap] {$\pi_i$} (Ai);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mention code you can't get working. Could we please see it? It might make a useful starting point. Also, do you want to do this in `tikz-cd`? You've tagged it that way? What problem are you having exactly? It is generally simpler to draw a non-bent arrow than a bent one, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks cfr, I had curved arrows that I was trying to get rid of as I has been trying to modify (without success) tikz code for the fibered product and there were curved arrows in that. It does seem easier to what I would like with straight arrows though. I added the code for the closest possible solution that I could find - the diagram was imploded on itself though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

Note that the use of the `positioning` library and the updated syntax `<direction>=of <place>` helps immediately with the spacing. Only one further adjustment really was needed here to increase the height a bit. The rest is just a question of tweaking the position of the labels e.g. `below` or `above` and using `sloped` for the 2 requiring that option.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (s) {$S$};
  \node (xy) [below=2 of s] {$X \times Y$};
  \node (x) [left=of xy] {$X$};
  \node (y) [right=of xy] {$Y$};
  \draw[->] (s) to node [sloped, above] {$f_y$} (y);
  \draw[<-] (x) to node [sloped, above] {$f_x$} (s);
  \draw[->, dashed] (s) to node {$(f_x,f_y)$} (xy);
  \draw[->] (xy) to node [below] {$\pi_X$} (x);
  \draw[->] (xy) to node [below] {$\pi_Y$} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: product]

Comment: It works! Very very nice and helpful. Thanks for the help and the explanation of what the problem had been with the previous code.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing commutative diagrams, I'd suggest you to use a dedicated package such as the powerfult [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) (built upon TikZ) which offer you a more convenient, cleaner and shorter syntax as well as ready to use features for your diagrams. A little example with your product:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
  & S\ar[dl,"f_{x}",swap,sloped] \ar[dr,"f_{y}",sloped] \ar[d,dashed,"{(f_{x},f_{y})}" description] & \\
X & X\times Y\ar[l,"\pi_{X}"] \ar[r,"\pi_{Y}",swap] & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: The question was originally tagged `tikz-cd`. I removed it because the question didn't mention it and the code didn't use it. (It was not originally tagged `tikz-pgf` even though the code used just that.) Should the other tag be restored? Maybe both tags? I kind of think it should have the more generic tag in addition, since the question didn't mention `tikz-cd` at all...?