# Connecting sections of a venn diagram with arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

What I am looking to do is to connect particular intersections of a venn diagram in 3 variables, with arrows. So for example, I manipulated the code 
[here: Venn Diagrams](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/) and shaded the intersections according to

```
$(A \wedge B \vee A \wedge C \vee B \wedge C) \wedge \neg (A \wedge B \wedge C)$
```

What I can't figure out how to do is to label these intersections and connect them with arrows.

Now, I realize the first code sample has a point in it which would correspond to the intersection of A,B, and C - but in case I would like to connect it in the future, I left it in there.

I can get the code to work to display, for example, derived from an answered question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258164/categorical-product-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node (G) [below right=1cm and 0cm of E] {$G = \{4,5,6,7\}$};
  \node (z) {$Z$};
  \node (xyz) [below=.8 of z] {$X \times Y$};
  \node (x) [below left=.578cm and 1cm of xyz] {$X$};
  \node (y) [below right=.578cm and 1cm of xyz] {$Y$};
  \draw[<->] (z) to node [sloped, above] {$ $} (y);
  \draw[<->] (x) to node [sloped, above] {$ $} (z);
   \draw[<->] (y) to node [sloped, above] {$ $} (x);
  \draw[-] (z) to node {$ $} (xyz);
  \draw[-] (xyz) to node [below] {$\pi_X$} (x);
  \draw[->] (xyz) to node [below] {$\pi_Y$} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as well as:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}


    \begin{document}
  \def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
    \def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
    \def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
        \begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};

        \begin{scope}
          \clip \firstcircle;
          \fill[pink] \secondcircle;
        \end{scope}

       \begin{scope}
          \clip \secondcircle;
          \fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}
          \clip \firstcircle;
          \fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}
          \clip \firstcircle;
          \clip \secondcircle;
          \fill[white] \thirdcircle;
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Thanks for any help,

Brian

Comment: What does the first example have to do with the second? I'm not clear what is wanted here.

Comment: Do note that courtesy (and, in some cases, the law) requires that code you obtain from others should be *attributed* i.e. you should acknowledge the source of the code you are using and not simply present it as your own original creation! Unless a user explicitly states otherwise, for example, code posted here is subject to a licence which requires attribution. But the main point, in my view, is that it is just rude not to acknowledge your sources.

Comment: Related, apparently: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258164/categorical-product-in-tikz.

Comment: Yep cfr, you got it! I added it to the original question. I absolutely have a lot of respect for the code people write, attempts made, and problems solved. Thus I will definitely keep in mind to reference.

Comment: No problem. Generally, people just don't think about it until somebody points it out. Then it seems obvious, but that doesn't mean it was obvious before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

After [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261679/connecting-sections-of-a-venn-diagram-with-arrows/261681?noredirect=1#comment627701_261681), this seems to be what is required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[pink] \secondcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[white] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\draw[name path=first] \firstcircle node[below] (A) {$A$};
\draw[name path=second] \secondcircle node [above] (B) {$B$};
\draw[name path=third] \thirdcircle node [below] (C) {$C$};

\path[name intersections={of=first and second,by={fs1,fs2}}];
\path[name intersections={of=second and third,by={st1,st2}}];
\path[name intersections={of=third and first,by={tf1,tf2}}];

\node 
  at ( $ (fs2)!0.33!(fs1) $ ) 
  (a) {a};
\node 
  at ( $ (st2)!0.33!(st1) $ ) 
  (b) {b};
\node 
  at ( $ (tf2)!0.33!(tf1) $ ) 
  (c) {c};
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (fs2) -- (st2);  
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (st2) -- (tf2);  
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (tf2) -- (fs2);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Something like this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[pink] \secondcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[white] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\draw \firstcircle node[below] (A) {$A$};
\draw \secondcircle node [above] (B) {$B$};
\draw \thirdcircle node [below] (C) {$C$};

\node 
  at ( $ (A)!0.5!(B) $ ) 
  (a) {a};
\node 
  at ( $ (B)!0.5!(C) $ ) 
  (b) {b};
\node 
  at ( $ (C)!0.5!(A) $ ) 
  (c) {c};
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (a) -- (b);  
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (b) -- (c);  
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (c) -- (a);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And, perhaps giving finer control, using the intersection poibts between the circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[pink] \secondcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip \firstcircle;
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[white] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\draw[name path=first] \firstcircle node[below] (A) {$A$};
\draw[name path=second] \secondcircle node [above] (B) {$B$};
\draw[name path=third] \thirdcircle node [below] (C) {$C$};

\path[name intersections={of=first and second,by={fs1,fs2}}];
\path[name intersections={of=second and third,by={st1,st2}}];
\path[name intersections={of=third and first,by={tf1,tf2}}];

\node 
  at ( $ (fs2)!0.33!(fs1) $ ) 
  (a) {a};
\node 
  at ( $ (st2)!0.33!(st1) $ ) 
  (b) {b};
\node 
  at ( $ (tf2)!0.33!(tf1) $ ) 
  (c) {c};
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (a) -- (b);  
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (b) -- (c);  
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (c) -- (a);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed Gonzalo, thank you. Do you know how one would go about connecting the furthest points of the intersections with lines, so as to create a full triangle. So what I mean is, connecting each of the 3 points in the intersections of A and B, but not C, just where A meets B, along with A and C (but not B), and B and C (but not A). So I suppose this would be a tangent line to A and C (which goes through B), B and C (which goes through A) and A and B (which goes through C), the tangent lines which all terminate at the intersection with the other lines. Thanks though for what you have posted.

Comment: @user1922184 Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you need? If not, please add an image to your question showing the desired result.

Comment: (+1) for skill in divination ;).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility which probably isn't what you want as it doesn't include any arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \fill[pink] \secondcircle;
    \fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \fill[white] \thirdcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
  \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
  \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
  \node [text=blue] at (30:20mm) {$B\wedge C$};
  \node [text=red, anchor=west, xshift=-2mm] at (90:10mm) {$A\wedge B$};
  \node (m) [text=green!50!black, below] at (0:10.5mm) {$\wedge$};
  \node [above=0pt of m, anchor=south, inner sep=0pt, text=green!50!black] {$A$};
  \node [below=0pt of m, anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, text=green!50!black] {$C$};
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \draw [green!50!black] \thirdcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \thirdcircle;
    \draw [green!50!black] \firstcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \draw [blue] \thirdcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \thirdcircle;
    \draw [blue] \secondcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \draw [red] \firstcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \draw [red] \secondcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \draw [red] \thirdcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \clip \thirdcircle ;
    \draw [blue] \firstcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \clip \thirdcircle ;
    \draw [green!50!black] \secondcircle;
  \end{scope}
  \node (p) [below=17.5mm, fill=pink, inner sep=0pt, text width=5mm, text height=5mm, draw] at (180:15mm) {};
  \node [right=2.5mm of p] {$((A \wedge B) \vee (A \wedge C) \vee (B \wedge C)) \wedge \neg (A \wedge B \wedge C)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the additional brackets are required to disambiguate the expression, as far as I know: `(A \wedge B) \vee C` is not equivalent to `A \wedge (B \vee C)`.

[image: labelled]

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but It does help in the display and useful, thank you.