# Categorical coproduct diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I would like something exactly like [Categorical product in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258164/categorical-product-in-tikz)

but with the arrows turned in the opposite direction.  I'm completely lost as I've never drawn a diagram like these before in LaTeX though I imagine the modifications needed are rather minor to flip the arrows.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: In the first solution in the question you link change `->` to `<-` to reverse the direction of the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As options of the `\ar` (alias of `\arrow`) macro, you find `u` = up, `d` = down, `l` = left and `r` =right.

To change the direction of an arrow, it is enough to invert those options and position the `\ar` macro at the new starting point.

With `swap` (which makes the label be placed on the right side of the arrow, relative to its direction, see the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf), p. 5), you can indicate where to put the labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    Original:   
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
        & S\ar[dl,"f_{x}",swap,sloped] \ar[dr,"f_{y}",sloped] \ar[d,dashed,"{(f_{x},f_{y})}" description] & \\
        X & X\times Y\ar[l,"\pi_{X}"] \ar[r,"\pi_{Y}",swap] & Y
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]

    With all arrows flipped:
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
        & S  & \\
        X\ar[ur,"f_{x}",sloped] \ar[r,"\pi_{X}", swap] & X\times Y \ar[u,dashed,"{(f_{x},f_{y})}" description] & Y \ar[ul,"f_{y}", swap,sloped] \ar[l,"\pi_{Y}"]
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Squirtle See my edit for further details.